# MY subquery does not work with error message

Tags: mysql, mariadb

When I run the query shown below it gives an error msg. Pls help me to correct it

```
select Debit_ID,Debit_Date,Debit_Note,Deb_Code,Debit_Amount,Settlement,Debit_Amount-Settlement as Balance
 from

(SELECT id Debit_ID,date Debit_Date ,reference_no Debit_Note ,customer_id Deb_Code,total Debit_Amount,
(select nvl(sum(amount),0) from sma_payments where type='received' and sma_sales.id=sma_payments.sale_id)Settlement
 from sma_sales where customer_id<>1 and sma_sales.sale_status='completed')
```

> [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries in `FROM` clauses need a table specifier i.e. `AS T` at the end:

```sql
SELECT
    Debit_ID,
    Debit_Date,
    Debit_Note,
    Deb_Code,
    Debit_Amount,
    Settlement,
    Debit_Amount-Settlement AS Balance 
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        id Debit_ID,
        date Debit_Date,
        reference_no Debit_Note,
        customer_id Deb_Code,
        total Debit_Amount,
        ( SELECT nvl ( sum( amount ), 0 ) FROM sma_payments WHERE type = 'received' AND sma_sales.id = sma_payments.sale_id ) Settlement 
    FROM
        sma_sales 
    WHERE
    customer_id <> 1 
    AND sma_sales.sale_status = 'completed') AS T;
```

For more information you can consult the MariaDB documentation:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/subqueries-in-a-from-clause/

Pro tip: when you properly format your SQL query it is much easier to debug.